# Analytic at a point x implies analytic at every point

Tags: real-analysis

I know the definition of analyticity of a function at a point. But if a function f is analytic at a point x then does it imply that f is analytic at every point in some open neighborhood of the point x. In other words is it possible or not for a function to be analytic at an isolated point.

Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you say that a function is analytic at some point $x_0$ if $f^{(n)}$ exists for every $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ and if$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n\tag1$$in a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$, is $f(x)$, then $f$ will be analytic too in every non-isolated point of $V$, precisely because $(1)$ holds in $V$.

Comment: I do not understand this answer. If $y_0$ is another non isolated point of $V$ why should we have$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(y_0)}{n!}(x-y_0)^n$$for any $x\in V$? Assume $f$ defined on an interval directly to avoid issues with isolated points.

Comment: @Hair80 I did *not* claim that this equality holds for every $x\in V$; only that it holds in a neighborhood of $y_0$. If (1) holds in the interval $(x_0-\rho,x_0+\rho)$, if $y_0\in(x_0-\rho,x_0+\rho)$, if $\tau>0$ is such that $|y_0-x_0|+\tau<\rho$, and if $x\in(y_0-\tau,y_0+\tau)$, then\begin{align}f(x)&=f((x-y_0)+y_0)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{m=n}^\infty\binom m{m-n}\frac{f^{(m)}(y_0)}{m!}\right)(x-y_0)^n.\end{align}So, on $(y_0-\tau,y_0+\tau)$ you can express $f(x)$ as the sum of some power series centered at $y_0$. When this occurs, the equality that you mentioned holds.